# Need fully qualified type name

Tags: c#, wpf, assembly-name

I need to resolve an assembly and type at runtime and I need to find the fully qualified type name.  For some reason I cannot get it right, as I keep get an exception saying it cannot find the type specified.

The app.config file, in which the assembly to look for is defined, looks like this:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Composite"/>
  </configSections>
  <modules>
    <module assemblyFile="G:\Data\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Race Management System.Shell\ConfigurationModularity\bin\Debug\Modules\Driver.Data.Module.dll" moduleType="Driver.Data.Module.DriverDataModule, DriverDataModule" moduleName="Driver.Data.Module.DriverDataModule"></module>
  </modules>
```

The assembly is called: *Driver.Data.Module*
Namespace in assembly is: *Driver.Data.Module*
and type name is: *DriverDataModule*, and this is also the name of the .cs file.

I cannot seem to find how to specify the name correctly in the xml file.  Can somebody help me with the fully qualified type name?

This is for a Composite WPF application.

Thanx!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `Driver.Data.Module.DriverDataModule, Driver.Data.Module`.

You can also find the full assembly-qualified name of your type by instantiating an object of that type and examining the AssemblyQualifiedName property of its Type:

```
DriverDataModule module = new DriverDataModule();
string fullyQualifiedName = module.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get? If you're having a hard time getting a full error message out of the app, and you think your app is having problems loading the assembly itself, you can use the [`fuslogvw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) tool to log full details to disk.

It's worth also opening the assembly in Reflector to double-check the assembly's full name (displayed on the bottom-left of the window when you open Reflector), and to check that the type is in fact defined in the namespace you think it is.